# Kurento disable video while video is streaming

Tags: webrtc, kurento

How to disable video streaming while video streaming is already invoked? Like in Facebook Messenger, it can turn video call to voice call only.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you'll have to tear down and recreate the whole connection with audio only, as Kurento does not support renegotiation. We are working on it, though!

Comment: Is this still valid? @igracia

Comment: I'm afraid this still holds, @Yash